# Cypress - automatically run all tests in browser, with hot reload

Tags: cypress

By default, running `cypress open` opens the Cypress window and *then I have to manually hit the "Run All Tests" button* to run them all.

How can run all tests in the browser just by running the `cypress open`, with no additional step?

Thank you.

Edit: I need the tests to rerun when I change the test files, just like `cypress open` does, so just running them once (like in headless mode) doesn't help.

Answer (score 12):

When using `cypress open` you can get tests to rerun in the browser after each edit by using the global configuration option `watchForFileChanges` as detailed [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Global)

You can pass this as a command line argument:

```
cypress open --config watchForFileChanges=true
```

Or you can specify it in your *cypress.json* file:

```
{
    "watchForFileChanges": true
}
```

You will still need to click *run all specs* when you first run `cypress open`, but after that any edit to the test files will cause the tests to be rerun.

Comment: I have got "watchForFileChanges": true already, but still the test runner is not running automatically after editting test spec.

Comment: @soccerway how are you running the tests? With `cypress run` or `cypress open`? The reason I ask is that the `watchForFileChanges` flag works with `cypress open`. It won't relaunch `cypress run`

Comment: Running tests using cypress open. Now I am using atom.js editor.  I have tried open the test file in notepad++ too, both way doesn't allow to run the test runner instantly after making changes

Comment: My test.js file is under ... `integration\examples\test.js` folder. I am using cypress 3.1.0 version and test runner Chrome 68 .I have opened cypress from Windows command prompt like this `C:\node_modules\.bin>cypress open'

Comment: Try running `cypress open --config watchForFileChanges=true` then choose your project directory.

Comment: I run the following `cypress open --config watchForFileChanges=true' from command prompt, click on the example-spec.js in app and edited again after the run in atom editor. Testrunner is not running again

Comment: @soccerway: in the Cypress desktop app that is launched with `cypress open`, click on the _settings_ menu button. Please post the JSON content so that others can help you troubleshoot it. You should open up a new question for this. You might also specify details such as the path to your project and the directory tree of your project. In short, I'm not sure why it appears Cypress is not rerunning the tests on file change, without sufficient details.

Comment: I have opened a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52320464/cypress-test-runner-is-not-instantly-running-when-the-example-spec-js-is-modif

Answer (score 9):

If you run Cypress tests headlessly `cypress run` it runs all tests without the need to click the "Run all tests" button.

I've found using `npx cypress run` is the best way to do this.
The documentation on running cypress headlessly specifies additional options you can use: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#

Comment: To clarify, I find `npx cypress run` best as I'm being lazy: it's quicker to type and you don't need to include the root cypress directory or `$(npm bin)`.

Comment: The thing is I want the tests in watch/hot-reload mode, to rerun when I change the tests and it'd be nice if they can run in the browser.

Comment: You can use the parameter `--browser` to specify that it should open a browser (Chrome is the only supported browser at the moment). Not sure if it runs in watch mode though.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Cypress UI's interface (remember that the Cypress UI lives in the DOM like any other page) to rerun the suite - just send some predefined signal from your app when it starts up, and let Cypress use jQuery directly (avoiding a log-event) to *find its own* reload button and click it.

In my example that "signal" is a certain console log message my React app burps up during its startup:

```js
Cypress.on("window:before:load", (win) => { // registers callback early, long before the app is loaded
  win.console._log = win.console.log;
  win.console.log = function monkeyPatchedConsoleLog() {
    if (arguments[0].match(/^MyApp starting: \(.*\)/)) { // match the app's startup message
      cy.$$(".restart", top.document).click(); // click Cypress' own reload button
    }
    return win.console._log.apply(win.console, arguments); // otherwise log normally
  };
});
```

(include this somewhere within your `support/*` files)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **npx cypress open**, then in **package.json** set the flag "setnonGlobalStepDefinitions" to false, and then indicate the folder containing the files in "stepDefinitions".

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^9.1.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
    "stepDefinitions": "cypress/integration/"
  }
}
```

Your tests will be run one after another.